# Svelte : Document Loaded inside onMount

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am new to Svelte. If understood what onMount does, it fires after components are loaded. If so, how do I call a function when all the images, and assets are available like window.load does?

```
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  onMount(() => {
    console.log('this fires')
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => {
      console.log('Nothing comes up in the console.')
    });
  })
```

Oddly this doesn't seem to fire.

Comment: In theory, you can listen to `window` events with [`<svelte:window>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-window), so you should be able to do `<svelte:window on:load={() => console.log('DOM loaded')} />` for instance. Never used this in practice, so I wouldn't be able to tell you if it indeed works, however.

Comment: @Thomas Hennes
 Thank you! I have already tried this before I posted this. It's odd though that it doesn't seem to log anything in console. I did indeed learn that I need to use <svelte:window> if possible as they made a separate api for this. After hours of work, I had to manipulate index.html to make this work.